# Creating A MP4 clip with Node js

Tags: node.js, video-streaming, streaming

Can I create video clips from an mp4 video with node js streams? I am sure there are npms for this task, but is this something that can be done with just streams?

When I create a server, I can pipe a brief clip from the beginning of a video to an **HttpResponse stream** and pipe it to a **file Stream** with the following code: (It works!)

```
const fs = require('fs');
const http= require('http');

http.createServer(async (req, res) => {

  // Creating clip from the beginning to 5% of the video
  var { size } = fs.statSync('./Fun.mp4');
  var start = 0
  var end = .05*size;

  var videoClip = fs.createReadStream('./Fun.mp4', { start, end })
  var fileCopy = fs.createWriteStream('./Fun-Copy.mp4')

  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'video/mp4'})
  videoClip.pipe(res)
  videoClip.pipe(fileCopy)

}).listen(3000);
```

However, if I change the start position to the middle of the video, it doesn't work. I don't see the clip in the web browser, and Qucktime cannot play the copy that was produced.

```
// Attempting to create a clip from 50% to 60% of the video
var { size } = fs.statSync('./Fun.mp4');
var start = 0.5*size;
var end = 0.6*size;
```

It seems like mp4 is incomplete without the beginning. Is there a way that I can create clips from a larger video file with streams. Is there some meta elements or something, or a specific number of bytes that need to be copied from the beginning of an mp4 file?

Does node js handle audio the same way? Can I build audio clips from a larger file with node js streams?

Comment: https://medium.com/@daspinola/video-stream-with-node-js-and-html5-320b3191a6b6

Comment: The code in this blog works because the initial request starts from bytes 0, which has the moov box. When a range request comes in the video will still play. I am attempting to obtain a video clip from the middle of an mp4 file and save that clip to a new mp4 file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a specific number of bytes needed. MP4 uses an index like structure to organize the files. If you modify the file at all, the index (called the moov box) needs to be rewritten in its entirety.

Comment: How do I copy the moov box into another clip? How can I figure out how many bytes are in the moov box?

Comment: You can’t copy it. You need to rewrite it. It is file specific. If you modify the file the old moov will point to data you removed, hence be corrupted.

Comment: Ok cool. Thanks for your time and answers. I appreciate it. I am just trying to understand why it works for specific cases. For Instance, it does work when I create clips from the beginning of the file. If I cut the first 10%, that clip steams to the browser and copies to a playable file. It also works with http "range" requests. Why does it work under these circumstances without rewriting the moov box?

Comment: The mp4 uses “pointers” inside the moov. These pointers record the exact byte offset of the media samples. In those cases you mentioned, you are not modifying the byte offset of any samples.

Comment: Ahhhh. Ok, great! Thanks.